# Webshpere Cast Iron Salesforce integration Unable to retrieve AccountContactRelation object from Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, websphere, integration

I am trying to retrieve records from Account Contact Relationship object in Salesforce in Cast Iron, but I am prompted with "Object type 'accountcontactrelation' unknown" error.

Answer (score 0):

found the answer to my question.  the cast iron orchestration is using salesforce api v29.  the account contact relation object is only available for api v32 or higher